# Plone 4 Redirection

Tags: plone

I have 3 plone sites with diffrent name in a standalone plone 4(version) installation. When i hit www.localhost:8000/ its displays all list of Plone sites. I want that if some user type www.localhost:8000/ then he should automatically redirect to my first plone site say abc i.e. www.localhost:8000/ points to www.localhost:8000/abc. And if some user type www.localhost:8000/xyz then its get xyz site (i.e. another plone site on the same server). How can i acheive this. In previous version i get it through index_html but in plone 4 they remove index_html. So i need some help. I'm new to Plone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: commonly those tasks are not done directly from Zope. Please consider using Apache, Ngnix, IIS or whatever, as a reverse proxy running on port 80. Use rewrite rules to map URLs to Plone sites. [Detailed instructions are available](http://developer.plone.org/hosting).

If your really don't want to use other HTTP server, you can use the Virtual Host Monster (virtual_hosting) in the ZMI root.